ControlNet Aux (ComfyUI): ImportError: cannot import name 'resize_image_with_pad' from 'controlnet_aux.util'
I just tried installing the ControlNet Auxillary (through the ComfyUI Manager, on Windows) but it returns this error: ImportError:
cannot import name 'resize_image_with_pad' from 'controlnet_aux.util'
When I load an image and feed it to Canny Edge it returns the same error.
I've tried updating ComfyUI, 'updating all', restarting, reinstalling the Auxillary and manually installing the dependencies from requirements.txt. So far, nothing worked.
Any idea on what I could try next? Or any additional info I could provide?
[comfyui_controlnet_aux] | INFO -> Some nodes failed to load:
        Failed to import module dwpose because ImportError: cannot import name 'resize_image_with_pad' from 'controlnet_aux.util' (C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\controlnet_aux\util.py)

Check that you properly installed the dependencies.
If you think this is a bug, please report it on the github page (https://github.com/Fannovel16/comfyui_controlnet_aux/issues)

Import times for custom nodes:
   0.0 seconds: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\websocket_image_save.py
   0.0 seconds: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-Advanced-ControlNet
   0.3 seconds (IMPORT FAILED): C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-ControlnetAux
   0.4 seconds: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-Manager
   0.6 seconds: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\comfyui_controlnet_aux

Starting server

To see the GUI go to: http://127.0.0.1:8188
FETCH DATA from: C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\ComfyUI-Manager\extension-node-map.json [DONE]
got prompt
!!! Exception during processing!!! cannot import name 'resize_image_with_pad' from 'controlnet_aux.util' (C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\controlnet_aux\util.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 151, in recursive_execute
    output_data, output_ui = get_output_data(obj, input_data_all)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 81, in get_output_data
    return_values = map_node_over_list(obj, input_data_all, obj.FUNCTION, allow_interrupt=True)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\execution.py", line 74, in map_node_over_list
    results.append(getattr(obj, func)(**slice_dict(input_data_all, i)))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\comfyui_controlnet_aux\node_wrappers\canny.py", line 18, in execute
    from controlnet_aux.canny import CannyDetector
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\ComfyUI\custom_nodes\comfyui_controlnet_aux\src\controlnet_aux\canny\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from controlnet_aux.util import resize_image_with_pad, common_input_validate, HWC3
ImportError: cannot import name 'resize_image_with_pad' from 'controlnet_aux.util' (C:\Users\user\Downloads\ComfyUI_windows_portable\python_embeded\Lib\site-packages\controlnet_aux\util.py)


Please post your full code and error.

I've added it to my post, is it sufficient?
